# Mongoose: having nested schemas with different key/values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am having the following situation:

A person can own multiple products. These products each have their own config fields.

I came up with something like this:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    productsOwned: [
        {
            _id: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Product'},
            configs: {}
        }
    ]  
})
```

and for product:

```
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    price: {type: Number},
    addedOn: {type: Date},
    description: {type: String},
    configs: {}
});
```

userconfig:

```
var UserConfigSchema = new Schema({
    product: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'}
});
```

I am not sure if i have to define another schema per product for the configurations and how they will be filled in accordingly

for example i want this:

```
var userConfig = new UserConfig({
    product: product._id,
    test1: "Hi",
    test2: [{
        server1: "blablbla",
        server2: {
            "blabla1": "hi1",
            "blabla2": "hi3"
        }
    }]
});

var userConfig2 = new UserConfig({
    product: product._id,
    "configkey1": "value1"
});
```

i am now using:

```
user.productsOwnedConfigs.addToSet(userConfig);
```

but it only adds the product key

Comment: What's the difference between the `configs` fields in `UserSchema` and `configs` in `ProductSchema`?

Comment: The configs in UserSchema are the configs the user has defined for a product. The configs in ProductSchema are the configs that Can be defined

Comment: Sounds like the `configs` in `UserSchema` is a subset of that in `ProductSchema`, right?

Comment: If so, It depends on how many possible configurations in the product. If the amount is not large and not duplicates with another product, you can define the `configs` in the `ProductSchema` as an array and `configs` in `UserSchema` just stores the indexes. Or, if the products's `configs` has a lot of duplicates with others or the amount of the `configs` are huge, you can use define another schema.

Comment: The configs can be huge, its not yet known since it could be that in the future we add products which have a huge config. But the configs per product can be different. So i guess i make a new Schema called UserConfig ? can this contain different value sets ?

Comment: If you mean each element in `configs` is unique in one kind of product, then, yes, `addToSet` is for that. "The `$addToSet` operator adds a value to an array only if the value is not already in the array".

Comment: I have added my original post with more details. is it possible to ever persist userConfig1 and userConfig2 ? or will i have to use inheritance for this perhaps?